# How to handle optional class members that are classes

Tags: c++

Specifically my problem is that I've created a Texture class (writing OpenGL code). The Texture class handles loading a file into memory, etc. and the constructor takes a filename as its parameter. Here's a snippet of some of the relevant code for that class.

```
class Texture
{
public:
    unsigned char* image;
    int width;
    int height;
    int channels;
    GLuint texture_id;

Texture(const char* image_path)
    :texture_id(NULL)
```

I then have a Pyramid class that *can* include a texture. It might simply be a colored pyramid with no texture though, so the texture attribute is optional.

```
class Pyramid :
    public Shape
{
public:
    std::string get_shape_type();
    Pyramid(float height, float base_width, glm::vec4 color, glm::mat4 scale, glm::mat4 rotation, glm::mat4 translation);
    Pyramid(float height, float base_width, const char * texture_file, glm::mat4 scale, glm::mat4 rotation, glm::mat4 translation);
private:
    Texture texture;
```

Of course, this gives me an error that the Texture class doesn't have a default constructor. What's the general pattern to use in this sort of situation? I tried including `texture(NULL)` as part of the constructor initialization list for Pyramid since the texture should only be set if a filename is passed in as part of the appropriate constructor, but that didn't clear up the error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: std::optional<Texture>?

Comment: "Of course, this gives me an error that the Texture class doesn't have a default constructor" its not clear what you mean. I don't see where a default constructor of `Texture` would be called in the code.

Comment: you can use `std::optional` . But if you need one instance of your texture to be shared by multiple shapes, then go for a (smart) pointer which you can set to `nullptr` whenever the shape has no texture.

Comment: A side note: `Texture` should better hold the image data in a `std::vector<unsigned char>` rather than using a raw pointer to a C array.

Comment: Your description says the `Pyramid` class can be a simple coloured pyramid or a textured pyramid. Since you inherit from `Shape`, wouldn't that suggest you have 2 classes, a `ColouredPyramid` and a `TexturedPyramid`?

Comment: Would you mind posting the definition (with initialization list) of  `Pyramid(float height, float base_width, const char * texture_file, glm::mat4 scale, glm::mat4 rotation, glm::mat4 translation);`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Simply declaring the member causes the constructor to be called any time a Pyramid object is instantiated. That's my understanding.

Comment: From this snippet it doesn't look like there's a `Texture` member variable at all in `Pyramid`. Is `Texture` a member of `Shape`? For anyone to be maximally helpful we probably need to see more code. To your question about patterning though: yes it's perfectly normal and common to use `NULL` (or ideally `nullptr`) for optional values and objects.

Comment: @JonReeves Missed a line in my copy and paste. It's edited now. Originally texture was a member of Shape, but since different subclass objects can have different numbers of sides and different numbers of textures I opted to push the texture down to the subclasses.

Comment: Thanks @TomH. The easiest way to fix your issue most generally is to actually create a user-defined default constructor that sets up the `texture` member to an "empty" state, however you define "empty". For example `Texture() : image(NULL) {}`. Note that initializing `texture_id` to NULL doesn't make a ton of sense, it's just an integer type (`GLuint`), and `NULL` or `nullptr` are usually declared as pointers. You probably want to just set it to plain `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers can help you with that. They can either reference a `Texture` or nothing (via `nullptr`).

```cpp
class Pyramid : public Shape
{
    Texture* m_Texture;

    Pyramid(Texture *tex = nullptr) m_Texture(tex) {};
};
```

Notes :

1. `Pyramid` may or may not be responsible for creating the texture depending on your need (meaning that the constructors could either require as parameters the `Texture*` or the `filename`)
2. A pointer will allow you to reuse the same `Texture` between many `Shape`s without loading them multiple times.